In the Cloudwatch events that goes over the size limit, how do I locate them?
I understand there is a size limit to a single cloudwatch log event, which is 256kb.
Of the events that goes over that limit, do they end up in a folder? Or I can easily identify them using CloudWatch insight?
Lastly, is it possible to use a trimmer to truncate the event at the limit, so it does not go over?

According to CloudWatchLogs line length limit - Stack Overflow, events longer than 256KB will fail.
